# How can I store 2 or 3 string pairs in a list in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a JAVA class that keeps a list of parts and sizes.  The class would also have a boolean flag.  The issue here is I know that there will be exactly 2 or 3 strings a single row (columns) BUT I don't know how many rows I'll have.  So I'm not sure of the syntax for the list of strings that will lock in the column count but not lock in the row count.  I'll also have addRow and updateRow methods.  This possible 3rd column would be updated knowing previous detail.

Not sure which is correct:

```
boolean myFlag;
String[][] myDetails = new String[][2];
String[] myDetails = new String[2];
```

Would be great if I could name the columns as well.

Comment: Use a `List<List<String>>`.  Then both inner list ( columns) and outer list (rows) can grow dynamically using the `add` method.

Comment: Or `List<Pair>` where `Pair` is a custom class (or `record` in Java 17 and later).

Comment: The point is ... don't use arrays when you want lists.  Arrays are a lot of work to manage "as lists".  It can be done *but it is not worth the effort* ... in the vast majority of use-cases.

Comment: @WJS I got this method working List<List<String>>. I can populate the list and print it, but I don't have my full solution working yet so not sure if it will do everything yet.  TY!!  I'll try to stop by later and give more feedback.

Comment: @WJS OK, that seams to be working fine.  TY again for the help.  As a follow up why do Java users prefer to use the templated types.  Yes those types seam to have additional functionality but templated types / classes usually bloat your code and are generally slower (in other languages).  Is that also true for Java?

Comment: @Keith  Imo, the API classes like `ArrayList` do not really add that much overhead.   And they do offer many methods to facilitate managing the class instances.  In the case of `ArrayList`, it is backed by an array with methods to `add, delete, insert`, along with many other less frequently use methods..  Lists also grow dynamically as values are added  To do the same with arrays, the users would have to implement those features themselves as methods in the main program or in a dedicated homegrown class and probably not as efficiently as they are done by the experts who developed the API.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a variable number of rows and a fixed number of columns, you may consider using:  `List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();`

To be more flexible, you can also use: `List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something generic, like `List<Map<String,String>>` to hold a variable number of Strings name-value pairs.

Given that you're dealing with lists of records with columns you want to name, is that set of columns static?  If it can suit your business case, I'd consider making a `Part` class that can support both cases.  Your named columns would be properties of that `Part` class, and you would add Part records to a `List<Part>`.